# Saving to localStorage not working in Firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I've been playing with this code, and I admit that I really don't know what I need to do to get it to work in Firefox or IE. Works great in Webkit and Opera. I can do basic HTML and CSS, but I'm clueless when it comes to JavaScript. I ran the code through jslint and it validated.

A general idea of what I'm doing; I have a form `name="f"`, textarea `onkeyup="doSetItem();"` with some dummy text, save link `onclick="addTodo(); return false;"`. When you click save, the textarea text should be saved to a hidden div. For the sake of brevity, I included a link to a fiddle I created that can be tested in all browsers. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/76hK4/13/)

Answer (score 0):

Which version of IE & Firefox are you using. You will need IE 8 and Firefox 3.5 for getting the support for Local Storage.

Here is how you can access them:
Saving form data to local storage -

```
 $("#save").click(function() {
    localStorage.setItem("tsk",$("#task").val());           
});
```

And retrieve them through:

```
$("#load").click(function(){
        $("#tasks").val(localStorage.getItem("tsk"));
});
```

I am using jQuery for selecting my DOM, but you can use access the local storage even without that.

Comment: Hi Abdel - I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to implementing. I understand what you're saying, but can you provide an example based on the code from the jsfiddle example I provided? Perhaps you can open it in Firefox and IE. Thanks for your time responding, Abdel